# Average weights in keras models

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

How to average weights in Keras models, when I train few models with the same architecture with different initialisations?

Now my code looks something like this?

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15,
                             width_shift_range=2.0/28,
                             height_shift_range=2.0/28
                            )

epochs = 40 
lr = (1.234e-3)
optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)

main_input = Input(shape= (28,28,1), name='main_input')

sub_models = []

for i in range(5):

    x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1)(main_input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)

    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(x)

    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)

    x = Dense(1024)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

    x = Dense(256)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)

    x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

    sub_models.append(x)

x = keras.layers.average(sub_models)

main_output = keras.layers.average(sub_models)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[main_output])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],
              optimizer=optimizer)

print(model.summary())

plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')

filepath="weights.best.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
callbacks = [checkpoint, tensorboard]

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / 128,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

So now I average only last layer, but I want to average weights in all layers after training each one separately.

Thanks!

Comment: You simply cannot average the weights of neural networks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What if you call `keras.layers.average()` between each layer?

Comment: Don't want to average between each layer because I want to train each models separately. In case averaging after each layer it's something different. Same is when I average models in last layer before training, that is also different.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes you can: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05407

Comment: @Scratch The paper doesn't support the idea that is asked in this question, its about averaging over SGD trajectories, and it appeared after this question was asked.

Comment: True. Averaging weights from models trained with different initialisations would make little sense. I just wanted to point out that averaging weights can be of interest in some specific cases.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So let's assume that `models` is a collection of your models. First - collect all weights:

```
weights = [model.get_weights() for model in models]
```

Now - create a new averaged weights:

```
new_weights = list()

for weights_list_tuple in zip(*weights):
    new_weights.append(
        [numpy.array(weights_).mean(axis=0)\
            for weights_ in zip(*weights_list_tuple)])
```

And what is left is to set these weights in a new model:

```
new_model.set_weights(new_weights)
```

Of course - averaging weights might be a bad idea, but in case you try - you should follow this approach.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea? I was inspired by http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#ensemble Where it is said that it's a good idea ;)

Comment: Just to give you one example why this might could go wrong - take a model and permute all filters in a consistent manner. The network will be mathematically equivalent - but the average could differ a lot from the original function. And I'm not claiming that this is bad idea - I claim that it might ;)

Comment: I have another issue. I get:
    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
I found that it is connected to fit_generator, but don't know how to fix this, can you help?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/miloszbednarzak/mnist/blob/master/mnist_averaged.ipynb

Comment: Change this line `new_model = model.set_weights(new_weights)` to `   `model.set_weights(new_weights)`

Comment: I made an implementation of that paper: https://github.com/simon-larsson/keras-swa

Comment: Great answer, I found that `sum(weights_) / len(weights_)` instead of `numpy.array(weights_).mean(axis=0)` speeds the function (`36 ms` instead of `91ms` with a 4 layer ANN and 1000 hidden neurons per layer). Is there a way to further improve it? I tried with multiprocessing but no luck so far

Comment: This is the approach that can be used for K-fold cross validation, right?

Comment: It's a good idea to average weights taken from same model during different epochs(usually few last epochs). It's a bad idea to average weights of different models(trained separately).

Comment: The error I get here is: `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Answer (score 10):

I can't comment on the accepted answer, but to make it work on `tensorflow 2.0` with `tf.keras` I had to make the list in the loop into a numpy array:

```
new_weights = list()
for weights_list_tuple in zip(*weights): 
    new_weights.append(
        np.array([np.array(w).mean(axis=0) for w in zip(*weights_list_tuple)])
    )
```

If different input models need to be weighted differently, `np.array(w).mean(axis=0)` needs to be replaced with `np.average(np.array(w),axis=0, weights=relative_weights)` where `relative_weights` is an array with a weight factor for each model.

Comment: I get an `TypeError: zip argument #5 must support iteration`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to compute the average of trainable parameters across multiple client models in TensorFlow/Keras. The averaging is done layer-wise. Here's the function I'm using:

```py
def average_client_weights(client_models):
    """
    Compute the average of the trainable parameters across multiple client models.

    This function takes a list of client models and calculates the average of their 
    trainable parameters. The averaging is done layer-wise, meaning that the average 
    for each layer is computed separately and then returned as a list of average weights 
    for each layer.

    Args:
    - client_models (list of objects): A list of objects representing the client models. 
      Each object is expected to have an attribute `trainable_variables` that returns a 
      list of `tf.Variable` objects representing the trainable parameters of the model.

    Returns:
    - avg_weights (list of tf.Tensor): A list of tensors representing the average weights 
      of the trainable parameters of the client models. Each tensor in the list corresponds 
      to the average weight for a specific layer.

    Example:
    If client_models[0].trainable_variables = [W1, b1, W2, b2], where W1, b1, W2, b2 are 
    tensors, then avg_weights = [avg_W1, avg_b1, avg_W2, avg_b2], where avg_W1, avg_b1, 
    avg_W2, avg_b2 are the average weights for each corresponding layer.
    """
    # Retrieve the trainable variables from each client model
    client_weights = [model.trainable_variables for model in client_models]

    # Compute the average weights for each layer
    avg_weights = [
        tf.reduce_mean(layer_weight_tensors, axis=0)
        for layer_weight_tensors in zip(*client_weights)
    ]

    return avg_weights
```